# How could a line of code cause Ruby to not recognize a - sign?

Tags: ruby, methods

While executing this line:

```
if behavior[i,0] <   Thrsh and theStim == "small" then fitness[0,i]-= 4 end
```

I get this error

```
EvoCat.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Most of it is copied from a program that runs fine, only 'theStim == "small"' is new but that seems Ok. I can't understand how I could do anything that would cause Ruby to no longer recognize a - sign. If it's not the line of code any hints where I should look for the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: `fitness[0,i]` is `nil` and `nil:NilClass` does not have a `#-` method. No idea what any of the variables are in this context.

Comment: Are you sure it is `fitness[0,i]`, not smth like `fitness[0][i]`? The former _is_ a valid Ruby code, but its semantics might be different from what you might expect - for an array, for example, this would be a "start,length" form that in fact returns a _slice_ of the original array (or nil if the length is negative). So the real question is what is `fitness` in this context?

Comment: Here's the fuller code that may help identify the problem with fitness:   fitness=Matrix.row_vector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])                                                   toward=[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
for i in toward 
if behavior[i,0] <   Thrsh and theStim == "small" then fitness[0,i]-= 4 end 
if behavior[i,0] <   Thrsh and theStim == "large" then fitness[0,i]+= 2 end
if behavior[i,0] <   Thrsh and theStim == "randm" then fitness[0,i]+= 1 end
end # for i

Comment: A friend identified the problem: a mismatch between the length of fitness (10) and the values in toward (>10).